# Função async e tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, telegram-bot

Estou tentando integrar a função async do Telethon abaixo ao commando de um botão no tkinter, mas não sei como proceder... A função abaixo funciona para envio da `message` ao `username`, porem gostaria que a mensagem fosse a variável `cpf`.

```
async def main():
    await client.send_message('username', 'message')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Tentei com o código código abaixo mas a função roda main logo ao inciar o código, e não no clique do botão, então `cpf` não existe ainda e recebo o erro `ValueError: The message cannot be empty unless a file is provided`

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from tkinter import *

api_id = xxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxx'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

root = Tk()
root.title('ME CONSULTAS')

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

cpf_entry = Entry(canvas)
cpf_entry.pack()
cpf = cpf_entry.get()

async def main():
    await client.send_message('consignadobot', cpf)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

search_btn = Button(canvas, text='Consultar', command=main)
search_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo o conceito async, no entanto você pode pegar o que contem no Entry dentro da função Main(), talvez isso resolva o problema.

```
async def main():
    await client.send_message('consignadobot', cpf_entry.get())
```